# GWT RequestFactory, ValueProxy or EntityProxy for collection/lookup table

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I am not sure what the best practice is for dealing with collection/lookup tables/in `RequestFactory`.

For example if I have following two Domain objects:

```
@Entity
public class Experiment  {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    private UnitOfMeasure unitOfMeasure;

    public Experiment() { }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UnitOfMeasure getUnitOfMeasure()  {
        return unitOfMeasure;
    }

    public void setUnitOfMeasure(UnitOfMeasure unitOfMeasure)  {
        this.unitOfMeasure = unitOfMeasure;
    }
}

@Entity
public class UnitOfMeasure  {
    private Long id;
    private String unit_type;

    public UnitOfMeasure() { }

    public String getUnitType() {
        return unit_type;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setUnitType(String unitType) {
        this.unit_type = unitType;
    }
}
```

This is a normal unidirectional 1:n realtionship between `Experiment` and `UnitOfMeasure` using a ForeignKey in the `Experiment` table.
I have a limited amount of different `UnitOfMeasure` instances which usually don't change.

The web-app provides a view where the user can change some properties of the `Experiment` instance. The view uses the `Editor framework`. For changing the `UnitOfMeasure` of a specific `Experiment` I use a `ValueListBox` and render the `unit_type` property.

Because the list of available `UnitOfMeasure` instances is static I use `AutoBeanFactory` to create a json string which I put into the HTML host page and during application start I parse it (same thing for all other collection like table values) and store them in a Singleton class instance (`AppData`) which I pass to `setAcceptableValues``.

Currently I derive `UnitOfMeasureProxy` from `EntityProxy` but in order to decode/encode it with `AutoBeanFactory` I have to annotate the Factory with `EntityProxyCategory`. I somehow suspect that a `ValueProxy` would be a better fit.
However with a `ValueProxy` when I change the `UnitOfMeasure` of a specific `Experiment` the entire `ValueProxy` instance is transmitted over the wire.
From a database point of view however only changing the value for the foreignkey in the `Experiment` table is required.

So what is the best practice (`ValueProxy` vs `EntityProxy`) for collection like tables and child values respectively?

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, references to other entities are best modelled using their IDs rather than the `EntityProxy`s themselves (it's debatable, but I think it's also true for server-side code, or actually any code that crosses unit-of-work boundaries –JPA EntityManager lifetime, Hibernate session, etc.–)

BTW, the proper way to serialize RequestFactory proxies is to use a [ProxySerializer](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/ProxySerializer.html).
Make sure you use GWT 2.5.0-rc1 though if you have lists of `ValueProxy`s (see [issue 6961](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6961))

Comment: Thanks for the tip with ``ProxySerializer``. Didn't know about that. But if I model references only by their IDs doesn't this entirely defeat the purpose of the ``ORM layer``/ ``RequestFactory``? 
In the tradtional example of ``Person`` and ``Address`` if I only model the relationship between ``Address`` and ``Person`` via the IDs rather than the entities itself I have to make sure to manually transmit the address when I want to display it? Same thing applies to the backend? What if I want to easily traverse from Person to Address? With only IDs I have to fetch it from the db?

Comment: You can map the relationship as read-only, and the IDs writable; i.e. `AddressProxy getAddress()` and `int getAddressId(); void setAddressId(int id)`. In the case of the Person/Address use case though, it's unlikely to be cross-session; this is not the same use-case as your `UnitOfMeasureProxy`s (that you keep in a cache for the whole lifetime of the application)

Comment: Ah ok I see. I guess I could do the same thing for collection like child values (``UnitOfMeasureProxy``) that are loaded once during application start and that are static regardless of the parent entity. In that case I might also ommit the getter for the actual entity at all, because I already have cached/loaded the list of all available types. In that case I probably can use a normal ``ListBox`` instead of a ``ValueListBox``.